# Configuring Intranet and Internet on one PC

Tags: networking, windows-vista

I have PC with two NICs one is connected to Internet and another is connected to Intranet.

Intranet settings are

```
10.35.134.129
255.0.0.0
10.35.134.1
```

Internet settings are

```
192.168.1.15
255.255.255.0
192.168.1.1

192.168.1.1
```

I am not able to use both at a time.

Comment: Hi, you should give us some more information. How are the the IPs set? DHCP? Static set on Client side? What is not working in detail?

Comment: For Intranet it is static, but for Internet it is DHCP but I have manually assigned the IP address. Actually I am able to access the Internet and Intranet simultaneously but not for long time, after that I am able to use Intranet but not Internet. Again when I DISABLE and then ENABLE internet connection I am able to use it for some time

Comment: INTRANET is on local office LAN and Internet is through Broadband MODEM.

Comment: I am slowly beginning to understand the setup. so the one is only for internet, and the other is for office, and eventually you lose the Internet altogether, But you dont lose the Office? You tried to static an Internet connection with an ISP? for our ISP that doesnt work anymore :-( When you no longer can get internet, can you ping by numbers (DNS)? does a renew/refresh work? (in win7 it is called "repair" dont know vista). Using CMD prompt Ipconfig will do it. Ipconfig /? for options. ipconfig /ALL for Info.

Answer (score 1):

[complete rewite]

If I under stand it correctly you have an intranet with 10.0.0.0/8 as numbering scheme.
(10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255, or up to 16777214 different addresses)

Your desktop has two network cards. One of them is connected to that intranet and it has the IP 10.35.134.1.

You also have a network with access to the Internet. That network is on 192.168.1.0/24 ( 192.168.1.0 - 192.1658.0.255, or up to 254 different addresses on this network).

Your desktops second NIC is connected to this network.

Since your desktop is multi-homed you will need to specify which network to use in the routing tables. You can set one (and only one) of them to the default for routes which are not specified.<sup>*1</sup>

Since you do not want to add routes to every single network on the Internet you want to use the gateway on that network as the default route.

This seems to match your

```
    Internet settings are
    192.168.1.15                The NICs IP
    255.255.255.0               The netmask for that net (a /24)
    192.168.1.1
```

I am guessing that 192.168.1.1 is the default gateway on that network.

However the other triplet confuses me.

```
10.35.134.129
255.0.0.0
10.35.134.1
```

I understand the IP and mask for the intranet LAN.  But the third value confuses me.

The only things I can **guess** at is that you have configured one or both of these NICs via DHCP, that you set the DG via DHCP and that the DHCP lease time for one of the networks is longer than that from the other, overwriting part of your settings when it is renewed.

Granted, that includes quite a few assumptions.

---

<sup>*1</sup> Technically not quite true. You can use multiple default routes. But only one will be used at any time.

Comment: OP has TWO (2) NICs. This answer seems to apply where the PC has ONE (1) NIC.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that you have access to both at the same time:

- You should edit the router settings
- Go to Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections
- Right click on your Network adapter
- Click on Properties > Check Internet Protocol TCP/IP v4
- Click on Properties of Internet Protocol TCP/IP v4
- Click on Advanced Tab > Uncheck the automatic Metric
- Choose a lower number for your wireless card vs your wired card.

You can check the current metric in cmd: `route print`

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the default gateway for your intranet (you must have one gateway: 10.35.134.1)
2. Add a route to the Windows routing table for sending Intranet traffic to 192.168.1.1.
   Run `cmd` and type:

   ```
   route -p  add 192.168.1.0  mask 255.255.255.0  192.168.1.1
   ```

Comment: How can the user "remove the default gateway for intranet"?  What is the command?  (Improve your answer by editing it.  Do not try to improve your answer by responding to my comment with another comment.)